# While trying to open native class in java open jdk 17, decompiled class without documentation is being opened

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I am using openjdk 17, vscode as IDE and maven springboot project.
While running as normal project works fine but running as maven project, it does not have source code documentation available for native java classes. Means, when I open a jdk file like List.class or ArrayDeque.class in the vscode IDE, the context inside has methods etc. but the documentation corresponding to the method is missing.

While opening List.class below text is opened with beginning of file looking like this:

```
// Source code is decompiled from a .class file using FernFlower decompiler.
package java.util;

import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
   int size();
```

I want it to look like this i.e. context of src.zip included:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1997, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS FILE HEADER.
 *
 * This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
 * under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 only, as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.  Oracle designates this
 * particular file as subject to the "Classpath" exception as provided
 * by Oracle in the LICENSE file that accompanied this code.
 *
 * This code is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License
 * version 2 for more details (a copy is included in the LICENSE file that
 * accompanied this code).
* Please contact Oracle, 500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA 94065 USA
 * or visit www.oracle.com if you need additional information or have any
 * questions.
 */

package java.util;

import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
```

How can I achieve this?
I am using VSCode but solution for other IDE is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your VS Code Java is using its own embedded JDK 17, which does not contain source code.

Please set the setting `"java.configuration.runtimes"`:

```
"java.configuration.runtimes" : [
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-17",
        "path": "<YOUR_JDK_LOCATION>"
    },
]
```

It should work after a window reload.

Comment: works like a charm! I tried many things but did not work out. Thank you so much.